# Create Images with watermark in extbase

Tags: image, typo3, extbase, watermark

I have a Model that stores a `FileReference`. And now I want to create an Image with a Watermark in the Extbase Controller. Does anybody know where I have to look for? I only found solutions with typoscript.

Comment: I did this in fluid template using `<f:cObject>` some time ago. I consider watermarking a presentational issue and thus like to keep it out of controller. In the end, TypoScript is doing the actual overlaying but you can set dimensions etc. from Fluid. Would that be acceptable for your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way will be to use a typoscript solution. This must not be as pure typoscript, but the datastructure of the typoscript might be needed as parameter to the core functions of the GifBuilder class.  [TYPO3 7.6 API](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/7/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_frontend_1_1_imaging_1_1_gif_builder.html)

The [GifBuilder](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/7/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_frontend_1_1_imaging_1_1_gif_builder.html) class is inherited from the class [GraphicalFunctions](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/7/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_imaging_1_1_graphical_functions.html) which can be used also, as there are only a few additions and the main functionality is here.

The last problem are the examples in the net according this task: they are pibased and all of them end up in something like

```
$img = $this->cObj->IMAGE($typoScriptArray);
```

in modern (namespaced) notation using current API this would be:

```
$gifCreator = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\GifBuilder::class);    
$gifCreator->init();     
$theImage=''; 
if ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['gdlib']) {     
    $gifCreator->start($fileArray, $typoScriptArray); 
    $theImage = $gifCreator->gifBuild(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I choosed the TypoScript way and it worked pretty well.

Fluid:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_myext.watermarkedImage" data="{imageUid:'{image.uid}',copyright:'{image.copyright}')}'}"/>
```

TypoScript:

```
lib.tx_myext.watermarkedImage = IMAGE
lib.tx_myext.watermarkedImage {
    file = GIFBUILDER
    file {
        XY = [10.w],[10.h]
        format = jpg

        10 = IMAGE
        10 {
            file {
                import.field = imageUid
                treatIdAsReference = 1
                width = 1162
                height = 580c
            }
        }

        20 = BOX
        20 {
            color = #FFFFFF
            opacity = 70
            dimensions = [10.w]-[30.w]-10,[10.h]-20,[30.w]+20,[30.h]+20
        }

        30 = TEXT
        30 {
            text.data = field:copyright
            fontSize = 15
            fontColor = #000000
            fontFile = path/to/my/font.ttf
            offset = [10.w]-[30.w]-5,[10.h]-5
        }
    }
}
```

The result is an image with a white box and the copyright text on it at the right bottom corner.